# Phalcon: how to require a .php file in my volt file?

Tags: phalcon

I am using Phalcon for the 1st time and I would like to migrate the content of an `index.php` file from my website into the `index.volt` file (in app/views).

So I tried to use `require 'header.php'` that I normally use in my index.php in the index.volt, like so:

**index.volt**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/index.css">

    </head>

    <?php require 'layouts/header.php' ?>
    <body onload="document.body.classList.add('loaded')" id="cool">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 400px;">
            {{ content() }}
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA-5rrW4FY43z63mHhwpv7BIZE3bv8Ws_A&libraries=places"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../public/js/index.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: require(layouts/header.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\care\cache\c__xampp_htdocs_care_app_views_index.volt.php
>   on line 14
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'layouts/header.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\care\cache\c__xampp_htdocs_care_app_views_index.volt.php
>   on line 14

So is there a particular way to include php file with phalcon ?

Thank you

Comment: You should use [partials](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/views#using-partials) to include small _partial_ views into other views

Comment: Does `header.php` contain only display logic?  If so, you should convert it to a volt file itself.  But your problem is the volt file is being run from the compiled template directory, and you're using a relative path that doesn't exist.  You're `require()`ing `C:\xampp\htdocs\care\cache\layouts\header.php`